# check if string contains any character on keyup

Tags: jquery, html, search, each, contains

I'm trying to make a live search on my site, I've got it working where the input field and link title match but it has to be the whole word. Is it possible to show any results that contain the specific value of the variable V in my code below:

HTML:

```
<form id="live-search" action="" class="styled" method="post">
       <input type="text" class="text-input" id="filter" value="" />
</form>


<div class="videoItems">
    <a title="Oliver" href="#" class="comedy"><img src="#" class="coverImg" alt="" /></a>
    <a title="Frank" href="#" class="scifi"><img src="#" class="coverImg" alt="" /></a>
    <a title="Ted" href="#" class="scifi"><img src="#" class="coverImg" alt="" /></a>
    <a title="James" href="#" class="scifi"><img src="#" class="coverImg" alt="" /></a>            
</div>
```

jQuery:

```
$("#filter").keyup(function(){
        var v = $('#filter').val().toLowerCase();
        if ( $('#filter')[0].value.indexOf('> <') !== -1 ){
            $('.videoItems a').show();                
        }
        console.log($('#filter').val());
        if($('#filter').val() == ''){
            $('.videoItems a').show();
        }else{
            $('.videoItems a').each(function(){
                var name = $(this).attr('title').toLowerCase();
                if(name == v){
                    $(this).show(); 
                }else{
                    $(this).hide(); 
                }
            });
        }
 });
```

I've also made a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/huddds/KfpG4/3/)

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution involves using `indexOf` to see if one string contains another.

If you want to both `oli` and `ive` to match `Oliver`, use this:

http://jsfiddle.net/vQLGG/

```
if (name.indexOf(v) > -1) {
```

If you want a "starts with" search, use this:

http://jsfiddle.net/NSnMH/

```
if (name.indexOf(v) == 0) {
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll probably have more flexibility if you use a regular expression for the search and it will work faster.

```
$("#filter").keyup(function(){
    var v = new RegExp($('#filter').val().toLowerCase(), "g");
    if ( $('#filter')[0].value.indexOf('> <') !== -1 ){
        $('.videoItems a').show();                
    }
    console.log($('#filter').val());
    if($('#filter').val() == ''){
        $('.videoItems a').show();
    }else{
        $('.videoItems a').each(function(){
            var name = $(this).attr('title').toLowerCase();
            if(v.test(name)){
                $(this).show(); 
            }else{
                $(this).hide(); 
            }
        });
    }
```

});